# Microsoft Graph .Net Client Library Is there a delay when using Group Delta?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

When creating new Groups with Microsoft Graph .Net Client Library and adding Owners, Members and a Team to the group, I noticed that using Delta on Groups to poll for changes is sometimes returning duplicates. I run this with no `$selects` and with `$expand` `members`

As a test I came up with this:

1. Get the latest Delta (*DeltaJunk*) on Groups, just to clear the delta (basically
   the same as `$deltaToken=latest`)
2. Create five Groups with one Owner, two Members (users referenced at the time of the group-creation) and a Team.
3. Sleep the thread for 10 seconds to allow for propagation
4. Get a new Delta (*Delta1*) on Groups, using the token from *DeltaJunk*
5. Sleep the thread for 10 seconds
6. Get yet another new Delta (*Delta2*) on Groups, using the token from *Delta1*

In the above scenario I suspected *Delta1* to return the five created groups, each containing the added members, and *Delta2* being empty, since nothing has been changed between the two last Delta-calls.

This is not always the case.

Sometimes *Delta1* contains only some of the groups and sometimes all. I would then suspect that *Delta2* might contain the groups missing from *Delta1* (due to changes not propagating fast enough before the next Delta-call), but that is not always the case.

Sometimes the same groups appear in *Delta2* as in *Delta1*, sometimes only some of them, sometimes different ones and sometimes not at all.

My *guess* is that the Delta calls don't trigger when the acctual change was requested. Rather, the requested change to the resources has to propagate all the way down before Delta can accurately report the updated state of the system.

For example, the Team hasn't been created at the time *Delta1* was requested but by the time *Delta2* is called, it has been created correctly and the change is reported correctly.

Can someone confirm this?

And if so, how long does one one need to wait before the changes has propagated safely all the way down? An hour? Two?

Comment: Typically takes 1-30 seconds depending on the current load in that tenant. I've seen it take a couple of minutes but _never_ an hour.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc mentioned changes can take up to a few minutes to show up in a delta query because of replications happening in the backend. If you experience a longer delay than this, you should open a support ticket to get the issue investigated